# How to determine the parent component - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on an existing program and I want to know if there is a way to **determine which is the parent component of the child component** ? In other words I want to realize **from where I'm receiving the props**

Assuming I have `test.vue` component and the purpose is to determine the value of `title` **where is coming from**

```js
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$parent` :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "one",
    };
  },
})

app.component('test', {
  template: `
    <div>{{ title }}</div>
    <hr />
    <p>From parent:</p>
    <div>{{ expectedProps }}</div>`,
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
  },
  computed: {
    expectedProps() {
      return this.$parent.$data
    }
  }
}) 
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <test :title="msg"></test>
</div>
```

Comment: well I just did **console.log(this.$parent.$data);** on a method on the child componenent and the output I got in my console is this **{__ob__: we}**

Comment: @ mawa frh hey mate, try with `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$parent.$data)))`

Comment: I attached the output in the post

Comment: do you have data property in parent component?

Comment: this is the point, I want to get the name of the parent component so I can check its data

Comment: mate if you have data property in your parent component `this.$parent.$data` will show it, look at the snippet pls

Comment: yet how could a parent pass to a child a property if it do not contain data property ? shouldn't the passed prop be defined in data() ?

Comment: not exactly , you can pass anything you want to prop, computed property, method...

Comment: well the app I'm working on is composed of multiple modules and I figured out that this property is received from another module..
I accept your response ;)